Adding joists to second floor above garage
My bonus room was made above the garage. The garage ceiling is drywalled, by not really finished. Would it be recommended to add more joists before putting a squat rack in the bonus room? Generally should this be something not too crazy to have done? The house was built in 2015 with the bonus room included

How much are you squatting?    I was doing 650 about 15 years ago and first thing I thought of was an extra layer of 1/2" plywood to deflect the load.    Really the questions are how much total weight are you squatting and how much total weight is in the bonus room.

Without knowing what the present floor support is, (size, spacing, span) it's entirely unknown whether the floor support is poor, marginal, good, or excellent as built.

Please revise to explain what a "squat rack" is and what it weighs. If the room was designed by a truss engineer it should comply with live load standards for any floor. Was it? If not, you'll need to be much more clear about the current framing situation.

If the room was designed, built and approved as a habitable room as part of a 2015 new construction in a place where there exists a building department and inspections, a squat rack will be fine in it.   Although the rack and all the plates are heavy, the weight is spread out across a relatively big area.
Imagine a sofa on 4 legs, with 4 large guys sitting on it.  Or a bathtub full of water.   Floors, in homes, are designed to support that kind of thing and a squat rack is not a bigger challenge.
If it's really a loft and you're calling it a bonus room, that's another matter.
If the rack has small feet, you might worry about your existing flooring so you should use wood tiles or a whole new layer of flooring to spread the load and ensure it transfers to the joists.
Although you call it a "squat" rack you can also do other things and if you do deadlifts ... do not drop a heavy barbell on your bonus room floor.  That seems obvious, but having equipment like this puts people in a frame of mind where they do things like that.
